# Настройка 404 ошибки в htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404

Есть файл htaccess со следующими настройками:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /?menu=$1 [QSA,L]
```

При вводе не верного url перебрасывает на главную страницу сайта. Где я ошибаюсь. Как исправить?

Answer (score 1):

В этом примере директива `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php` не имеет смысла, т.к. конструкция

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /?menu=$1 [QSA,L]
```

по факту является реализацией "обработчика" статуса "Страница не найдена".

И следуя всем правилам в вашем примере, mod_rewrite в итоге "остановится" на правиле `RewriteRule ^index.php$ / [QSA,R=301]`

Поэтому определяйтесь, что вам в итоге надо.